# Relaying denied. IP name possibly forged [216.136.38.14]')} Python error

Tags: python, email, smtp, ip

I am trying to send mail using SMTP server but I am getting error but the same code is working using gmail.so can you help me to fingd the solution.

```
from smtplib import SMTP
import datetime

debuglevel = 0

smtp = SMTP()
smtp.set_debuglevel(debuglevel)
smtp.connect('e3-smtp-gtm.zxp.com', 25)

from_addr = "from mail id"
to_addr = "to mail id"

subj = "hello"
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime( "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" )

message_text = "Hello\nThis is a mail from your server\n\nBye\n"

msg = "From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\nDate: %s\n\n%s" % ( from_addr, to_addr, subj, date, message_text )
smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg)
smtp.quit()
```

When I run above code I am getting error as below

{'to mail id': (550, b'5.7.1 ...Relaying denied. IP name possibly forged [216.136.38.14]')}

Can anyone help me what is main reason for getting this error

Answer (score 0):

An SMTP server is a protected resource without public access. Without the restrictions spammers would misuse it a lot.

While everybody may submit messages that will be delivered locally (incoming mail), only authorized users may submit messages to be forwarded to other servers on Internet (outgoing mail). Usually the authorization is based on IP address or user/password login.

The meaning of "Relaying denied" is that the SMTP server does not recognize you as an authorized user who can send email wherever he wants. You should provide login/password given to you by the server's admin. In most cases that requires STARTTLS prior to login.

Also, connecting to port 25 is discouraged. This port is intended for server to server mail transfer. The initial message submition should go to the TCP port 587.

Comment: yeah you are right,But Admin mentioned that There is NO username or password required to establish a connection  and Admin only give port number as 25 and all other details.

Comment: @Paramesh Using port 25 is an outdated practice, but when it is OK by your admin, just go ahead and use it. It is not a main cause of the problem anyway.  Usually, when there is no username and a password, your PC must be connected to the internal LAN of your company, school, organization etc. The SMTP server knows the IP address range of local computers. In any case, "relaying denied" means that you are treated like a "stranger" by the SMTP server. Your email appears like coming from outside and going to outside, that's what the term relaying means.